# How to export a quasar app as a web component

Tags: vue.js, webpack, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to build a quasar app as a web component, for which I am planning to use vue custom element.

I did the following changes,

```html
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers';
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue';
//@ts-ignore
import vueCustomElement from 'vue-custom-element';
import * as BaseApp from './../App.vue';
import { App } from "vue";

let custElement: any;
export default boot(({app,router,store}) => {
    custElement = vueCustomElement;
    //@ts-ignore
    BaseApp.default.store = store;
    //@ts-ignore
    BaseApp.default.router = router;
    const CustomElement = defineCustomElement({props:BaseApp.default.props,setup:BaseApp.default.setup,name:BaseApp.default.name,store:BaseApp.default.store,router:BaseApp.default.router})
    customElements.define('test-app', CustomElement)
});

export { custElement };
```

Did the following changes in quasar.conf.js file to disable chunking

```html
chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.resolve.symlinks(false);
        config.optimization.splitChunks(false);
        config.output.filename('js/app.js');
      },
      filenameHashing: false,
      pluginOptions: {
        webpackBundleAnalyzer: {
          openAnalyzer: false,
        },
      },
      configureWebpack: {
        output: {
          libraryExport: 'default',
        },
        devServer: {
          disableHostCheck: true,
        },
      },
      extendWebpack(cfg) {
        cfg.plugins.push(
          new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
            maxChunks: 1,
          })
        );
        
        const vueLoaderRule = cfg.module.rules
        .find(el => el.test.toString() == /\.vue$/.toString())
    
      const ruleFirstLoader = vueLoaderRule.use[0]
      const options = ruleFirstLoader.options
    
      // change options
      options.transpileOptions = {
        transforms: {
          dangerousTaggedTemplateString: true
        }
      }
      },
```

Added the custom element in the index.template.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= productName %></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="<%= productDescription %>">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width<% if (ctx.mode.cordova || ctx.mode.capacitor) { %>, viewport-fit=cover<% } %>">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="128x128" href="icons/favicon-128x128.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="icons/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- DO NOT touch the following DIV -->
    <!-- <div id="q-app"></div> -->
    <test-app id="q-app"></test-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

When running the app, the rendered html content will look like the below,

[Rendered Vue Custom Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUIDf.png)

I am not sure where the issue is. It would be grateful if I got any suggestions to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/6172, https://juanignaciogarzon.medium.com/creating-a-web-component-with-vue-quasar-188007ec999e

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks for your reply. I found an npm package which helped to componentize the quasar app.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-webcomponent-wrapper
Hope this may help someone

Comment: Can you share some details how were you able to do this, did you made any amends to .quasar folder files?